# Check if given time lies within a specific range in php laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here is my scenario,

Suppose we have a food truck, which has a daily schedule and scheduled has a starting time and ending time. The starting time of the truck is **09:00:00** and ending time us **12:00:00**. If user enter following inputs
**Scenario1:**
start_time = 09:00

**out_put**
true and return a schedule

**Scenario2:**
start_time = 11:00

**out_put**
true and give a schedule

**Scenario3:**
start_time = 12:00

**out_put**
true and give a schedule

**Scenario4:**
start_time = 11:00

end_time = 12:00

**out_put**
true and give a schedule (because it lies in the interval)

I have written following query to check these scenarios

```
    public function search_schedule($time){
     if (isset($time['start_time']) && count($time) > 0) {
      $sql->where(function($sql) use ($time){                              
      $sql->where('start_time', '<=', date("H:i:s",strtotime($time['start_time'])));
      $sql->where('end_time', '>=', date("H:i:s", strtotime($time['start_time'])));    
 });
       }
     if (isset($time['end_time']) && count($time) > 0) {
        $sql->where(function($sql) use ($time) {
        $sql->where('start_time', '<=', date("H:i:s", strtotime($time['end_time'])));
        $sql->where('end_time', '>=', date("H:i:s", strtotime($time['end_time'])));
          });
       }
    }
```

This snippet is working perfectly fine for the scenarios mentioned above. Only one scenario is creating problem. The scenario is

**Scanario**

Start_time: **08:00:00**

end_time: **11:00:00**

It should return the schedule because end_time is in the interval 9-12

What should I do in this regard?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Is it working for Scenario Start_time: **10:00:00** end_time: **13:00:00**?

Comment: no it is not working